# WiX installer - problems updating

Tags: wix

I'm having the worst time trying to configure WiX to NOT remove some configuration files from the installation directory during updates.

I've searched and googled but I'm stuck...

Here's what I have.

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" ... >
  <Product Id="PRODUCT_GUID" ...
     UpgradeCode="UPGRADE_GUID">
    ...
    <Upgrade Id="$(var.UpgradeCode)">
       <UpgradeVersion OnlyDetect="no" Property="REMOVEOLDVERSION" Maximum="$(var.ProductVersion)" IncludeMaximum="no" />
       <UpgradeVersion OnlyDetect="yes" Property="NEWERFOUND" Minimum="$(var.ProductVersion)" IncludeMinimum="no" />
    </Upgrade>


    <InstallExecuteSequence>
      <RemoveExistingProducts After="InstallFinalize" />
    </InstallExecuteSequence>
    ...
```

And the files are as followed:

```
   <Component Id="ConfigurationFiles" Guid="ConfigurationFiles_GUID" NeverOverwrite="yes">
      <File Id="SomeConf" Source=... />

    </Component>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the problem is really the *removal* of the configuration files, then I think you meant to specify `Permanent="yes"` instead of `NeverOverwrite="yes"`.

However, if the configuration files are not installed by the new version of the installer (which is why they disappear after the upgrade, I presume) then they shouldn't be necessary right? I'm not sure why you would want to keep the configuration files in that case. Marking them permanent effectively makes it impossible to uninstall them.

If you are actually worried about *overwriting* changes made to those configuration files by the user, then I think Windows Installer will already handle this correctly. The [File Versioning Rules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368599%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) already have a concept of "user data" based on file modification timestamps, and will not overwrite such files.